# How to connect ADLS account with Azure VM

Tags: java, azure, authentication, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I have followed this site https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/08/05/accessing-azure-data-lake-store-using-webhdfs-with-oauth2-from-spark-2-0-that-is-running-locally/ to connect ADLS storage with my Azure VM.

- Created Azure VM and installed my application in it
- Created Azure Data Lake Store and service pricipal

Here is my core-site.xml:-

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.oauth2.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.oauth2.access.token.provider</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.oauth2.ConfRefreshTokenBasedAccessTokenProvider</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
        <value>https://login.windows.net/tenaid-id-here/oauth2/token</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.oauth2.client.id</name>
        <value>Client id</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.oauth2.refresh.token.expires.ms.since.epoch</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.oauth2.refresh.token</name>
        <value>Refresh token</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I have installed my application in Azure VM and I get following error when I upload file in my application.

```
2017-01-27 12:54:25.963 GMT+0000 WARN  [admin-1fd467a4c41f43fe9f30ab446a5c93ac-84-b6792518109848bead029c9144603d04-libraryService.importDataFiles] LibraryImpl - Failed to write data file partID: 0 at:  library/51dc056c0a634beba243120501fe70d6/545ca95c2a894f948b1f5184b013a53e/5c68d893090f471d81f3cdfc810bc4f7/b6d5ceb64bfd4d65ba4ea24d24f99e90
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/clusters/myapp/library/51dc056c0a634beba243120501fe70d6/545ca95c2a894f948b1f5184b013a53e/5c68d893090f471d81f3cdfc810bc4f7/b6d5ceb64bfd4d65ba4ea24d24f99e90/data (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/palmtree/work/software/myapp-2.5-SNAPSHOT/myapp)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:150)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:176)
    at parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:93)
    at com.myapp.hadoop.common.PaxParquetWriterImpl.doWriteRow(PaxParquetWriterImpl.java:52)
    at com.myapp.hadoop.common.PaxParquetWriterImpl.access$000(PaxParquetWriterImpl.java:19)
    at com.myapp.hadoop.common.PaxParquetWriterImpl$1.run(PaxParquetWriterImpl.java:43)
    at com.myapp.hadoop.common.PaxParquetWriterImpl$1.run(PaxParquetWriterImpl.java:40)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at com.myapp.hadoop.common.PaxParquetWriterImpl.writpeRow(PaxParquetWriterImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.myapp.hadoop.core.DistributionManager$$anon$10.invoke(DistributionManager.scala:313)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.writeRow(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.library.stacks.DataFileWriter.write(DataFileWriter.java:49)
    at com.myapp.library.LibraryImpl.pullImportData(LibraryImpl.java:747)
    at com.myapp.library.LibraryImpl.importDataFile(LibraryImpl.java:631)
    at com.myapp.frontend.server.LibraryAPI.importDataFile(LibraryAPI.java:269)
    at com.myapp.frontend.server.LibraryWebSocketDelegate.importDataFile(LibraryWebSocketDelegate.java:189)
    at com.myapp.frontend.server.LibraryWebSocketDelegate.importDataFiles(LibraryWebSocketDelegate.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketProtocolHandler$PXMethodHandler.call(PXWebSocketProtocolHandler.java:144)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketEndpoint.performMethodCall(PXWebSocketEndpoint.java:284)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketEndpoint.access$200(PXWebSocketEndpoint.java:47)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketEndpoint$1.run(PXWebSocketEndpoint.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-01-27 12:54:25.966 GMT+0000 WARN  [admin-1fd467a4c41f43fe9f30ab446a5c93ac-84-b6792518109848bead029c9144603d04-libraryService.importDataFiles] LibraryImpl - Failed to import acquisition da73b76755c34c74a1643a324e41e156
com.myapp.iface.service.RequestFailedException
    at com.myapp.library.LibraryImpl.pullImportData(LibraryImpl.java:754)
    at com.myapp.library.LibraryImpl.importDataFile(LibraryImpl.java:631)
    at com.myapp.frontend.server.LibraryAPI.importDataFile(LibraryAPI.java:269)
    at com.myapp.frontend.server.LibraryWebSocketDelegate.importDataFile(LibraryWebSocketDelegate.java:189)
    at com.myapp.frontend.server.LibraryWebSocketDelegate.importDataFiles(LibraryWebSocketDelegate.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketProtocolHandler$PXMethodHandler.call(PXWebSocketProtocolHandler.java:144)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketEndpoint.performMethodCall(PXWebSocketEndpoint.java:284)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketEndpoint.access$200(PXWebSocketEndpoint.java:47)
    at com.myapp.frontend.util.PXWebSocketEndpoint$1.run(PXWebSocketEndpoint.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Kindly help to solve this

**Update 1:-**

Tried the following to connect My application on Azure VM with ADLS:-

1. Added [azure-data-lake-store-sdk](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/microsoft/azure/azure-data-lake-store-sdk/2.1.4/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar) in lib
2. I have followed this [Service-to-service authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-authenticate-using-active-directory#create-an-active-directory-application) to create application in Azure Active Directory .
3. I have also assigned the Azure AD application to the ADLS account root directory.

   `Root directory -> /clusters/myapp`
4. Updated core-site.xml based on values from above documentation.

   ```
   <configuration>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.adls.home.hostname</name>
       <value>dev.azuredatalakestore.net</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.adls.home.mountpoint</name>
       <value>/clusters</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>fs.adl.impl</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.adl.impl</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.Adl</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
       <value>https://login.windows.net/[tenantId]/oauth2/token</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id</name>
       <value>[CLIENT ID]</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.credential</name>
       <value>[CLIENT KEY]</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type</name>
       <value>ClientCredential</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>fs.azure.io.copyblob.retry.max.retries</name>
       <value>60</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>fs.azure.io.read.tolerate.concurrent.append</name>
       <value>true</value>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
       <value>adl://dev.azuredatalakestore.net</value>
       <final>true</final>
     </property>

     <property>
       <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
       <value>360</value>
     </property>

   </configuration>
   ```
5. I am getting following error when I start my application Server in VM:-

   ```
   2017-02-02 07:40:27.527 GMT+0000 INFO  [main] DistributionManager - Looking for class loader for distroName=adl kerberized=false
   2017-02-02 07:40:28.428 GMT+0000 ERROR [main] SimpleHdfsFileSystem - Failed to initialize HDFS file storage on null as hdfs root /myapp
   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.validateResponse(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:347)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.access$200(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:98)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:623)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:472)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:502)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:498)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.mkdirs(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:919)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1877)
       at com.myapp.hadoop.common.HdfsFileSystem$1.run(HdfsFileSystem.java:98)
       at com.myapp.hadoop.common.HdfsFileSystem$1.run(HdfsFileSystem.java:91)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
       at com.myapp.hadoop.common.HdfsFileSystem.__initialize(HdfsFileSystem.java:91)
       at com.myapp.hadoop.common.SimpleHdfsFileSystem.initialize(SimpleHdfsFileSystem.java:40)
       at com.myapp.hadoop.hdp2.HadoopDistributionImpl.initializeHdfs(HadoopDistributionImpl.java:63)
       at com.myapp.hadoop.hdp2.UnsecureHadoopDistributionImpl.connectToFileSystem(UnsecureHadoopDistributionImpl.java:22)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at com.myapp.hadoop.core.DistributionManager$$anon$1.invoke(DistributionManager.scala:135)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.connectToFileSystem(Unknown Source)
       at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.parseSimpleAuthFileSystem(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:126)
       at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.initializeStorageWithPrefix(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:64)
       at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.initialize(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:39)
       at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.initialize(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:33)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:274)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106)
       at com.myapp.container.PxBeanContext.getBean(PxBeanContext.java:156)
       at com.myapp.library.streaming.files.UploadFileServiceImpl.initialize(UploadFileServiceImpl.java:49)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
       at com.myapp.container.PxBeanContext.startup(PxBeanContext.java:42)
       at com.myapp.jetty.FrontendServer.main(FrontendServer.java:124)
   2017-02-02 07:40:28.462 GMT+0000 WARN  [main] server - HQ222113: On ManagementService stop, there are 1 unexpected registered MBeans: [core.acceptor.dc9ff2aa-e91a-11e6-9a51-09b76b4431e6]
   2017-02-02 07:40:28.479 GMT+0000 INFO  [main] server - HQ221002: HornetQ Server version 2.5.0.SNAPSHOT (Wild Hornet, 124) [7039110c-dd57-11e6-b90d-2bc6685808f5] stopped
   2017-02-02 07:40:28.480 GMT+0000 ERROR [main] FrontendServer - Fatal error trying to start server
   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myapp.library.streaming.files.UploadFileServiceImpl#0' defined in class path resource [system-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl#0' defined in class path resource [system-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized
       at com.myapp.container.PxBeanContext.startup(PxBeanContext.java:44)
       at com.myapp.jetty.FrontendServer.main(FrontendServer.java:124)
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myapp.library.streaming.files.UploadFileServiceImpl#0' defined in class path resource [system-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl#0' defined in class path resource [system-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
   at com.myapp.container.PxBeanContext.startup(PxBeanContext.java:42)
   ... 1 more
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl#0' defined in class path resource [system-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:274)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106)
   at com.myapp.container.PxBeanContext.getBean(PxBeanContext.java:156)
   at com.myapp.library.streaming.files.UploadFileServiceImpl.initialize(UploadFileServiceImpl.java:49)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
   ... 11 more
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized
   at com.myapp.hadoop.common.SimpleHdfsFileSystem.initialize(SimpleHdfsFileSystem.java:45)
   at com.myapp.hadoop.hdp2.HadoopDistributionImpl.initializeHdfs(HadoopDistributionImpl.java:63)
   at com.myapp.hadoop.hdp2.UnsecureHadoopDistributionImpl.connectToFileSystem(UnsecureHadoopDistributionImpl.java:22)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at com.myapp.hadoop.core.DistributionManager$$anon$1.invoke(DistributionManager.scala:135)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.connectToFileSystem(Unknown Source)
   at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.parseSimpleAuthFileSystem(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:126)
   at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.initializeStorageWithPrefix(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:64)
   at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.initialize(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:39)
   at com.myapp.library.LibraryStorageImpl.initialize(LibraryStorageImpl.scala:33)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
   ... 28 more
   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.validateResponse(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:347)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.access$200(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:98)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:623)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:472)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:502)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:498)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.mkdirs(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:919)
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1877)
   at com.myapp.hadoop.common.HdfsFileSystem$1.run(HdfsFileSystem.java:98)
   at com.myapp.hadoop.common.HdfsFileSystem$1.run(HdfsFileSystem.java:91)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
   at com.myapp.hadoop.common.HdfsFileSystem.__initialize(HdfsFileSystem.java:91)
   at com.myapp.hadoop.common.SimpleHdfsFileSystem.initialize(SimpleHdfsFileSystem.java:40)
   ... 47 more
   ```

Using following jars in my project:-

```
azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar
hadoop-azure-datalake-3.0.0-alpha1.jar
hadoop-common-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar
hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar
hadoop-hdp2-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Clarifications:-

1. My intention is to connect My application on Azure VM with DataLake Store with out need of HDInsight Cluster. Is that possible ? If so what steps should I need to follow ? What are the configuration needs to be present in core-site.xml ?
2. File preview fails with AccessControlException error in ADLS
3. Login the HDInsight cluster which is associated to the Data Lake Store using ssh command - ssh [user]@[cluster2]-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
4. Copy a file to the cluster using the wget command - wget http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv
5. Create a new folder in your Data Lake Store account
6. Now upload a file using PUT command
   hdfs dfs -put Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv adl://dev2.azuredatalakestore.net/new
7. View the file in the Azure Portal

Actual Result: The file is uploaded and shows in the Azure Portal. But, file preview is broken and I see the below error

```
AccessControlException
OPEN failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.). [4f97235c-0852-44c8-a8d4-cbe190ffdb34]
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Hey karan, can you tell me how did you generated RefreshToken. I am struck in that part, ending up with an error :: ls: Error fetching access token

Comment: @KiranKrishnaInnamuri Refer https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/08/05/accessing-azure-data-lake-store-using-webhdfs-with-oauth2-from-spark-2-0-that-is-running-locally/

Comment: @kaaran what did u use curl or postman?

Comment: I have use postman

Comment: In postman while i am trying to generate, it is throwing 400 error! i am suspecting that the code might be wrong, in the code up to where we need to copy before &session_state or after that also? Can you please help me with this.

Comment: code=yourtoken&session_state. Take yourtoken and use it.

Comment: yes! i am able to generate the refresh token. When i am using it in my core-site.xml, i am getting ls: Error fetching access token error again.

Comment: @KiranKrishnaInnamuri Check you core-site.xml key,values, all values are valid?

Comment: Yeah! tnq @karan, all my values are correct but it is still unable to generate the access token, so i have changed the provider type of clienCredential  and the issue is resolved.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we really do not recommend that you use the swebhdfs path.  As called out in Arsen’s blog, the adl client is much more performant.  Here are directions for configuring the adl filesystem:
[Hadoop Azure Data Lake Support](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html)

For your specific error, it looks like the `mkdir` is invoked on the local file system as shown by the "file:" in the output of the mkdir command.

To solve the error, follow the steps mentioned in Arsen’s blog.  After configuration, run hdfs command on the swebhdfs path like

```
bin\hadoop> fs -ls swebhdfs://avdatalake2.azuredatalakestore.net:443/
```

One more thing:  Since posting that blog, Azure Data Lake now has full support for the Java SDK.  Here is an article that describes how to use the Java SDK to perform basic file operations:

[Get started with Azure Data Lake Store using Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk)

-- Cathy

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to connect to ADLS is to use the Java SDK that Cathy mentioned in her response.

[Get started with Azure Data Lake Store using Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk)

In your example why are you trying to connect from your Azure VM with the data lake store using the Hadoop client?  Using the Hadoop client is a more convoluted way to achieve the seemingly simple scenario of connecting from your app on an Azure VM to ADLS.

The Hadoop client is typically what people do to connect existing Hadoop clusters to ADLS. I have a feeling that is not what you are trying to do. Let us know if this is not the case.